# Pin big logo header into menu while scrolling down

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have HTML logo header like :

```
<div id="header-inner">
    <a href="#" style="display: block">
        <img alt="Zalaro" height="90px;" id="Header1_headerimg" src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Gl1C_jIZzzw/VitZSSDKfAI/AAAAAAAAH1M/UXQQKPV5XTU/s1600-r/2.png" style="display: block" width="270px; "/>
    </a>
</div>
```

And menu:

```
   <ul>
        <li><a class="thome" href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Models</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
```

I want to pin logo (http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Gl1C_jIZzzw/VitZSSDKfAI/AAAAAAAAH1M/UXQQKPV5XTU/s1600-r/2.png) while scrolling down(>100px) into "Home" position.

It means we have :

```
 <li><a class="thome" href="#"><img alt="Zalaro" height="90px;" id="Header1_headerimg" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvfCJ.png" style="display: block" width="270px; "/></a></li>
```

I also want to return orginal logo, menu while scrolling up (<100px).

I have used but I do not know how to do:

```
var num = 100; 
$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > num ) {
    }
    else{
   }
});
```

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Javascript-Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var num = 100;
    var home = $('.thome');
    var homeContent = home.html(); //save the current htmlContent of .thome
    var image = $('#Header1_headerimg');

    $(window).bind('scroll', function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > num ) {
            //Clone the Image and insert it into the .thome class
            home.html(image.clone());
        } else {
            //Replace the content of .thome with the "Home"-Text
            $(".thome").html(homeContent);
        }
    });
});
```

This will replace the Content of the `li.thome` Element with the `#Header1_headerimg` Image if you scroll further down than 100px.

The normal Content of the `li.thome` is saved in the `homeContent` variable and will be reset if you scroll to top again.